# Android Switch button color not changing in 4.0.4

Tags: android, button, switch-statement, textcolor

I have used Switch button, everything works fine when the app run it on 4.2 and above, but the text color not at all changed to white in 4.0.4 i have tried all possible solution

My Switch :

```
<Switch
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/facilityassetdescription"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/offbuttonbg"
        android:textColor="@style/toggle_text"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:textOn="ON"
        android:thumb="@drawable/switchselector" />
```

My style file

```
<style name="toggle_text">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/toggle</item>
    </style>
```

res/color/toggle_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <!-- Default State -->
    <item android:color="#ffffff"/>

</selector>
```

Kindly give any idea to get rid of this problem

Comment: Both the colors are white? Did you check by changing one of the colors?

Comment: Here both displays black. instead of white

Comment: Try giving the text color attribute a drawable, instead of a color. Put the toggle_text.xml in the drawable folder and set the textColor="@drawable/toggle_text" and see if it works.

Comment: yeah sure, let me check

Comment: did you tried giving android:textColor="#FFFFFF" ?

Comment: @KumarBibek tried with  textColor="@drawable/toggle_text" but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below style:

```
<style name="toggle_text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/toggle</item>
</style>
```

And, In xml file for switch mention android:switchTextAppearance attribute instead of using android:textColor:

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/facilityassetdescription"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/offbuttonbg"
    android:switchTextAppearance="@style/toggle_text"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON"
    android:thumb="@drawable/switchselector" />
```

Comment: Great, its working. android:switchTextAppearance="@style/toggle_text" the answer is with this line right?

Answer (score 4):

> You can use Switch-Compat intend of Switch using support v7
>   library.Try new concept
>
> **my.xml**
>
> ```
> <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
>     android:id="@+id/sc_push"
>     style="@style/switchStyle"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>     android:theme="@style/switchStyle"
>     app:theme="@style/switchStyle" />
> ```
>
> **style.xml**
>
> ```
> <style name="switchStyle">
>     <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/red</item>
>     <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/gray</item>
> </style>
> ```
>
> Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

Use support 7 SwitchCompat

and put `<item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#E21D1D</item>` in your style
and   `<item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#E21D1D</item>` in your theme

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/switch_options"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    app:showText="false" >
                </android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat>
```

Gud Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

for anyone if the above answers did not work try this..

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/switch_is_in_stock"
                style="@style/proximaNovaNormalColorBlack.size14"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textColor="@color/switch_thumb_selector"/>
```

answer is on this xml line ->  android:textColor="@color/switch_thumb_selector"